# Is there a way to limit the duration of an audio capture in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

In my Codename One app, I need to limit the duration of an audio capture to few seconds. I call `Capture.captureAUdio()` for that and there does not seem to be an equivalent to `Capture.capturePhoto(w, h)` that could bound the captured audio to a given duration.

What I've done so far is measure the audio capture duration and if it is too long then ask the user to start again if they will. But I find it a bit cumbersome.

Is there anything better that can be done ?

Any hint appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For audio though you can use use the media recording feature from `MediaManager` which isn't as intuitive as `Capture` but allows more "fine grained" control.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, you're right I could start the recording manually with Media and stop it after the desired duration. Great tip!